# r - xpathApply on XMLNodeSet (with XML package)

Tags: html, r, web-scraping

I am trying to use xpathApply function in XML package in R to extract certain data from a html file.
However, after I use xpathApply on some parent nodes of the html document, the class of the resulting object becomes XMLNodeSet, and I cannot further use xpathApply on such object, as this error message appears: “Error in UseMethod("xpathApply") : no applicable method for 'xpathApply' applied to an object of class "XMLNodeSet"”

Here is the R script I am trying to replicate my problem (this example is just a simple table, I know I can use readHTMLtable function, but I need to use more low level function to work because my actual html is more complicated than this simple table):

```
library(XML)
y <- htmlParse(htmlfile)
x <- xpathApply(y, "//table/tr")
z <- xpathApply(x, "/td")
```

Here is the “htmlfile”:

```
<table>
<tr>
<td> Test1.1 </td> <td> Test1.2 </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td> Test1.3 </td> <td> Test1.4 </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Is there any method to further work on the nodes after using xpathApply? Or are there other good alternatives to play around the data in the nodes?

Answer (score 2):

Once you have a list of node you can apply function on itto extract the node. Function like `xmlValue` or `xmlGetAttr`....
For example :

```
x <- xpathApply(y, "//table/tr")
sapply(x,xmlValue)          ## it a list of nodes..
 " Test1.1  Test1.2 " " Test1.3  Test1.4 "
```

Which is equivalent to do :

```
xpathSApply(y,"//table/tr",xmlValue)
" Test1.1  Test1.2 " " Test1.3  Test1.4 "
```

**EDIT**

I am sure that you question can be solved by the right xpath. You should learn  work with xml files as you work with a data base . xpath is just analogous to an sql query. it is fast and many browsers  can help you to get  the generate the right xpath.

For example :

```
 xpathSApply(y,"//table/tr[2]/td[1]",xmlValue) #  second tr and first td
 [1] " Test1.3 "
 xpathSApply(y,"//table/tr[2]/td[3]",xmlValue) #  second tr and third td
```

**EDIT**

THE OP  looks like if he wantes to replicate the XML structure ( get tr and td in the same order)

here is the way , I don't think is the more efficient way ...

```
nn.trs <- length(xpathSApply(y,"//table/tr",I))
lapply(seq(nn.trs),function(i){
       xpathSApply(y,paste("//table/tr[",i,"]/td",sep=''),xmlValue)
})
[[1]]
[1] " Test1.1 " " Test1.2 "

[[2]]
[1] " Test1.3 " " Test1.4 "
```

If if number of td are all same in each tr, you can replace `lapply` by `sapply` and you get :

```
    [,1]        [,2]       
[1,] " Test1.1 " " Test1.3 "
[2,] " Test1.2 " " Test1.4 "
```

But I think that in this case readHtmlTable is better..

Comment: I don't think that's what OP wants. He wants to further search the results of first xpathApply

Comment: @geektrader I am waiting for you answer to clarify what do you mean by further search the results...

Comment: I mean he wants to search for sub elements of the result. `td` in this case

Comment: Thanks for the discussion and suggestions. Actually I would like to point to and retrieve any particular element at convenience, say if i want to get second tr first td, then I can get the "Test1.3"; or if there are three td in seond tr instead of two (while first tr unchanged and still has only two td, in this case it is not a regular table anymore), if I want to get the third td of second tr, I can easily point to that and get that. That's why I said I want to do xpathApply twice. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: Thanks agstudy, two more question, if I do not know in advance how many elements in each tr and how many tr in total, and 1) want to automatically place each tr into list and each td into sub-list; and 2) if number of td are all same in each tr, place them into a matrix; are there ways to do that?

Answer (score 2):

Although the solution of defining the right xPath seems to be better you can do this:

```
library(XML)
y <- htmlParse(htmlfile)
x <- getNodeSet(y, "//table/tr")
z <- lapply(x, function(x){
                 subDoc <- xmlDoc(x)
                 r <- xpathApply(x, "/td")
                 free(subDoc) # not sure if necessary
                 return(r)
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Following seem to be working. Essentially you have to search the elements of the list returned by `xpathApply`

```
> y <- htmlParse(htmlfile)
> x <- xpathApply(y, "//table/tr")
> x
[[1]]
<tr><td> Test1.1 </td> <td> Test1.2 </td>
</tr> 

[[2]]
<tr><td> Test1.3 </td> <td> Test1.4 </td>
</tr> 

attr(,"class")
[1] "XMLNodeSet"
> z <- xpathApply(x[[1]], "//td")
> z
[[1]]
<td> Test1.1 </td> 

[[2]]
<td> Test1.2 </td> 

[[3]]
<td> Test1.3 </td> 

[[4]]
<td> Test1.4 </td> 

attr(,"class")
[1] "XMLNodeSet"
```

**PS: I am not sure why it searches all elements of `x` list rather than just `x[[1]]`. Seems like a bug.**

Comment: it is better to use `xpathSApply`  something like  `xpathSApply(y,"//table/tr/td",I)`

Comment: this last comment really helped!

Comment: I think you find all the `td` elements because `//` means starting from root; you should have writen `"./td"`.