# R-extracting data from XMLNodeSet

Tags: r, xml, xpath, xmlnodelist

I am trying to extract data from html document with XML package.
I go as following:

```
library(XML)
sink("parse.txt")
parse<-htmlParse(file = "jdwaz.html",encoding = "GBK")
a=getNodeSet(parse,'//div[@class="amount"]')
print(a)
```

then class(a) returns "XMLNodeSet", its content looks like this in txt file

```
[[1]]
<div class="amount">
                    <span>总额 ￥113.80</span> <br /><span class="ftx-13">在线支付</span>
                                    </div> 

[[2]]
<div class="amount">
                    <span>总额 ￥99.00</span> <br /><span class="ftx-13">在线支付</span>
                                    </div>
```

I only show 2 of 20 of "a"

class(a[1]) returns "list"
I want to get the content "总额 ￥99.00".
I found one method in [r - xpathApply on XMLNodeSet (with XML package)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14957632/r-xpathapply-on-xmlnodeset-with-xml-package)
It uses xmlvalue to get text like:

```
x <- xpathApply(y, "//table/tr")
sapply(x,xmlValue)          ## it a list of nodes..
 " Test1.1  Test1.2 " " Test1.3  Test1.4 "
```

but it doesn't fit my situation.
When I enter xmlvalue(a),it returns:

```
Error in UseMethod("xmlValue") : no applicable method for 'xmlValue' applied to an object of class "XMLNodeSet"
```

I didn't find suitable method to deal with XMLNodeSet-class.
HELP!

Comment: @Zelbinian  I found you asked question which is relevant to my question, I wonder whether you can help me

Answer (score 3):

I am using `rvest` package for scraping data from webpage and have run into a similar problem as you.

In `rvest`, you get data via `html_nodes(read_html(url), css)` to get xml nodeset similar to your `a`. I learned a quick way to extract content from xml nodesets via a simple function `html_text()`. To use it, you wrap `html_text()` around the xml nodeset.

Assuming the following example to get company name based on its domain:

```
library('rvest')
url <- 'https://who.is/whois/gmail.com' 
webpage <- read_html(url)
a <- html_nodes(webpage,'.col-md-7')
a[1] # returns the long xml nodeset
html_text(a) # converts the xml into vector with content extracted
html_text(a)[2] # gives you the company name
```

It looks like `rvest` is a popular package for web data scrapping and there's a lot of help resources on it as well.

Answer (score 2):

To query an XML node set, use a leading "." so its relative to the current node.  Since you have two span tags, get the one without the class attribute.

```
sapply(a, function(x) xpathSApply(x, ".//span[not(@class)]", xmlValue)) #OR
sapply(a, xpathSApply, ".//span[not(@class)]", xmlValue)
[1] "总额 ￥113.80" "总额 ￥99.00"
```

Comment: thanks a lot, i use **/span/text()** to get the content between a pair of tags.
now i have a new question, i use xmlGetAttr to get content in <>
for example, <td data-nick=“**淘票票**”...........>
the content i want is in **Chinese**, then R returns the content in wrong words. i guess it is because of the encoding way, but there’s no relevant set inxmlGetAttr function. Sad….

Comment: I found **iconv** function, it helps with the encoding problem!